# Java JDBC connection for oracle database with ussername.tablename

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have a oracle database where I can connect using the hostname and system id with a userid and password say 'userread' as userid and 'password1'. After connection in the database there are other users say user1, user2 etc these user has tables and I can query these tables using 'select * from user1.table1' in sql developer

But when I use jdbc I can connect to the database using hostname and system name with userid and password i.e 'userread' and 'password1' as mentioned above. But after connection when I try to query a user table 'select * from user1.table1' its failing saying table doesnot exist.

Please let me know what is the correct way to handle this scenerio so that I can create connection using the user 'userread' and query other user table the same manner as sql developer

Answer (score 1):

After connecting to the database with that username, you can use the query 'select * from table1'. You don't need the username again.